# Problem with interacting with python via pipe() C call

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am trying to write a C-program for Linux, which would be able to interact with other programs via pipe() calls. The following code doesn't work, however exactly the same works if I change "/usr/bin/python" to "/bin/cat" (I mean, the line is printed out)

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
        int inpipe[2], outpipe[2], pid, in_bytes;
        char *cmd[] = {"python", (char *) NULL}, buff[1024];
        pipe(inpipe);
        pipe(outpipe);

        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                dup2(inpipe[1], 1);
                dup2(inpipe[1], 2);
                dup2(outpipe[0], 0);

                prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);

                execve("/usr/bin/python", cmd, NULL);
        }
        close(inpipe[1]);
        close(outpipe[0]);

        write(outpipe[1], "print \"lol\"\n", 12);
        in_bytes = read(inpipe[0], buff, 1024);
        write(1, buff, in_bytes);

        close(inpipe[0]);
        close(outpipe[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw, yes, I checked if python is installed and that /usr/bin/python is the correct program. Changing to python2 doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `python` only behaves like a REPL by default when input is a tty. Without a tty, it's just a REP:

```
# Hangs until the pipe is closed with Ctrl+D
{ echo 'print "lol"'; cat; } | python
```

You have multiple options depending on what you want to do. Two of them include:

1. Run `python -i` instead to get a REPL (`char *cmd[] = {"python", "-i", (char *) NULL}`). This will show all the interactive prompts and such, so you'd have to read more data.
2. Close the pipe so that Python knows the script is done. This will make it execute it.

Here's your code adapted to do that:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
        int inpipe[2], outpipe[2], pid, in_bytes;
        char *cmd[] = {"python", (char *) NULL}, buff[1024];
        pipe(inpipe);
        pipe(outpipe);

        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                dup2(inpipe[1], 1);
                dup2(inpipe[1], 2);
                dup2(outpipe[0], 0);
                close(outpipe[0]);
                close(outpipe[1]);

                prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGTERM);

                execve("/usr/bin/python", cmd, NULL);
        }
        close(inpipe[1]);
        close(outpipe[0]);

        write(outpipe[1], "print \"lol\"\n", 12);
        close(outpipe[1]);
        in_bytes = read(inpipe[0], buff, 1024);
        write(1, buff, in_bytes);

        close(inpipe[0]);
        close(outpipe[1]);
        return 0;
}
```